# can I use conv2d with input dimension not fixed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i am new in tensorflow i have a question : Can i put in my conv2d an input with shape not fixed ?
inputs.shape =(?, 1568)
when i train my neural network i get this message :
`raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" ' ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (Dimension(None), Dimension(1568))`
my con2d layer is like this :
 `x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same",input_shape=input_shape[1:])(inputs)`

Comment: The problem is not fixed dimension, for Conv2D your data is not an image, it should have four dimensions: (samples, width, height, channels).

Comment: in input shape ?

Comment: yes, the shape of the inputs

Comment: inputs.shape =(?, 1568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that by using `tf.expand_dims`